# How can I tell why my website uses LocalStorage and IndexedDb)?

Tags: html, local-storage, indexeddb

When I visit my website using Google Chrome, Chrome shows (in "Cookies and Site Data") that it's using LocalStorage and IndexedDB. I'm not deliberately doing so, and I'd like to find out why those are appearing in the list.

The site does use a few 3rd-party things, notably (perhaps) Google Universal Analytics and Google Tag Manager, but I checked the JS source for both of those (including the file that gets downloaded on the fly), and could find no obvious references to LocalStorage or IndexedDB (though it's not exactly easy to read the minified code).

Is there any way to tell what's using those features?

FWIW it's an ASP.NET MVC5 website, though I doubt that's relevant.

Comment: does anything show in the resources tab in the chrome dev tools?

Comment: @Wobbles: I hadn't looked, but no: no actual values are shown...

Comment: Perhaps that's just google chrome's interpretation of cached files then?

Comment: Hmmm... but it doesn't show anything for other websites...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have specific code doing this, then third party analytics/ads are the likely culprit. Here's what I'd try:

1. Use `chrome://settings/cookies` and delete the storage for your site
2. Identify a page in your site that causes the data to be written
3. Modify the page to have an inline script before any other scripts are loaded, that shims the storage APIs with dummy functions like:

   window.indexedDB.open = function() {
       throw Error('Indexed DB');
     };
     window.localStorage.setItem = function() {
       throw Error('DOM Storage');
     };
4. Reload the page with the developer console open. If you're lucky you'll see exceptions thrown with a stack trace pointing to the code that tried to use those functions.
5. If not, change those `throw` lines to simply `debugger;` to invoke the debugger, and reload the page again. The call stack in the debugger should show you what library is using the storage APIs.